# Divided by some number into column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Well, I have a number which stored in a column. If I want to divide the value, I just need:

`select columnName / 12 from myTable`

Is it possible to put the result into 12 column? I want to make the `12` is flexible. So for instance, if I divide the value by 4, so the result should be 4 column.

```
Value      Result1     Result2     Result3     Result4
12000      3000        3000        3000        3000
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?
Thank you.

Comment: What Does value of `12000, 3000, and so on` mean?

Comment: the result if divided by 4 @Phong

Answer (score 0):

This achievable using dynamic query.

```
declare  @cols nvarchar(max);
declare  @sql nvarchar(1000);

        with cte as (
                select 12000 as col1, 12000/4 as col2
                union all 
                select col1-col2, col2 from cte where col1 > col2
        )

select @cols =
        STUFF((select N',' + QUOTENAME(col2) from cte
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 1, '') + N'';

select @cols
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to be dynamic query

Check below

```
Create TABLE Table1 (Origional int)

Declare @DivisonValue INT = 4

insert into Table1 
VALUES (12000)

--Change the Top (12) to you what ever number you like. this will be your total number of columns
DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT 
                        ',' + C.ColumnName + ' = Origional / ' + CAST(@DivisonValue AS VARCHAR(5))
                        /* Above line which you need to change for division */
                    FROM 
                        (SELECT TOP (@DivisonValue)
                                ColumnId    = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
                            ,ColumnName ='Result' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id]))
                        FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
                        ) AS C
                    ORDER BY
                        C.ColumnId
                    FOR XML PATH (''))          

DECLARE @FullQuery VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT Origional,'+ substring(@Columns,2,LEN(@Columns)-1) + ' FROM Table1' 

EXEC (@FullQuery)

DROP TABLE table1
GO
```

Change the logic as per your need for division.

Comment: this one is correct, but the result is wrong. if the value is 12,000 then the other value if divided by 4... should be 3000 for each column.

Comment: if i divided by 4, then the result column should be 4,.with value is 3,000. your code creates 12 columns.

Comment: Yes, this is OK. Is it possible to add the original value on the first column?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid dynamic SQL if you know a maximum count:

Start with a *mockup-table* to simulate your issue

```
DECLARE  @tbl TABLE(InitialValue DECIMAL(16,4));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(12000),(20000),(10000);
```

--To test this I use a divisor of 4, try with other numbers

```
DECLARE @divisor DECIMAL(16,4)=4;
```

--This is the query

```
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT t.InitialValue / @divisor As DivResult
          ,t.InitialValue
          ,CONCAT('div',FORMAT(A.Nmbr,'00')) AS ColumnName
    FROM @tbl t
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP(CAST(@divisor AS INT)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM master..spt_values) A(Nmbr)
) t
PIVOT
(MAX(DivResult) FOR ColumnName IN(div01,div02,div03,div04,div05,div06,div07 /*add as many as you might need*/)) p;
```

The result

```
InitialValue    div01                   div02                       div03                       div04                       div05   div06   div07
10000.0000  2500.000000000000000000000  2500.000000000000000000000  2500.000000000000000000000  2500.000000000000000000000  NULL    NULL    NULL
12000.0000  3000.000000000000000000000  3000.000000000000000000000  3000.000000000000000000000  3000.000000000000000000000  NULL    NULL    NULL
20000.0000  5000.000000000000000000000  5000.000000000000000000000  5000.000000000000000000000  5000.000000000000000000000  NULL    NULL    NULL
```

As you can see, the unused columns are returned but stay NULL.

I'd prefer this approach over dynamic sql as the consumer is better of in most cases if the result set and its structure is fixed and predictable...

Hint: You can add the divisor to your result set if needed...

Comment: the divider column number should be dynamic, this is manual column.